# Dynamically create Aggregate pipeline for mongo-go-driver

Tags: mongodb, go

https://godoc.org/github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver

I am trying to create an Aggregate pipeline dynamically. For example, I want to read a slice of string containing the oceans. I tried breaking these apart to pieces, but I could not find any methods to append elements.

```
pipeline := bson.NewArray(
    bson.VC.DocumentFromElements(
        bson.EC.SubDocumentFromElements(
            "$match",
            bson.EC.SubDocumentFromElements("ocean",
                bson.EC.ArrayFromElements("$in",
                    bson.VC.String("Pacific Ocean"),
                    //bson.VC.String("Indian Ocean"),
                ),
            ),
            bson.EC.SubDocumentFromElements("callTypeName",
                    bson.EC.ArrayFromElements("$in",
                        bson.VC.String("Wookie"),
                        bson.VC.String("Unknown 13"),
                    ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
)
cur, err := collection.Aggregate(context.Background(), pipeline)
```

Comment: You mean like [`Append()`](https://godoc.org/github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/bson#Array.Append)? It's a little broad a question since you don't actually say "which parts" you want to "dynamically" construct. So I'm a little unsure how to interpret your question other than you appear to not be aware of where the [API documentation](https://godoc.org/github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver) is. As you can see by visiting the links, there's quite a bit of it. Perhaps you coul be more descriptive in your question about what "dynamic construction" you actually intend to do here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought the question was pretty clear, not sure if the first commentor was actually reading the statement carefully.

What this person was asking was to dynamically insert data given a list of data into the pipeline.

I had the same issue on a vue app my team and I are working on. Using your provided data, here is the general template:

Given a slice of string of oceans

```
a := []string{"Pacific Ocean", "Indian Ocean"}
```

Make a slice of size 0 of type *bson.Value

```
b := make([]*bson.Value, 0)
```

Loop through the slice of oceans and append bson converted values to slice b

```
for _, v := range a {
    b = append(b, bson.VC.String(v))
}
```

Then create key-value pair so that mongo can look for matches

```
c := bson.EC.ArrayFromElements("$in", b...)
```

Then pass c into the pipeline

```
pipeline := bson.NewArray(
    bson.VC.DocumentFromElements(
        bson.EC.SubDocumentFromElements(
            "$match",
            bson.EC.SubDocumentFromElements("ocean", c),
        ),
    ),
)
```

This should give you an idea on how to dynamically pipeline for callTypeNames

Comment: This works for me. I totally forgot about passing a slice on a variadic function. Thank you!